# How to calculate $\lim _{x\to \infty }x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil}\right)^x$$

My thoughts are to use the limit of the euler number, but I think that the book "wants me" to calculate it with the following lemma:

If f is two times derivative in the interval I, with $a \in I. \forall x \in I, f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac 12f''(z)(x-a)^2, z$ is in between $a$ and $x$. Particularly, $\epsilon(x)=\frac12f''(z)(x-a)^2$

Another thing I'm thinking about is:

$$x=2y  \Rightarrow  \lim _{x\to \infty }x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil}\right)^x=
\lim _{y\to \infty }2y\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{y}\rceil}\right)^{2y}\\ =
\lim _{y\to \infty }2y\sin\left(\exp\left(2y\ln\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{y}\rceil}\right)\right)\right)$$

Am I going through the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin(x)\le x$ for all positive real $x$:

$$\sin\left(\frac{2}{\lceil{x}\rceil}\right)\le\frac{2}{\lceil{x}\rceil}, $$

where

$$\frac{2}{x+1}\le \frac{2}{\lceil{x\rceil}}\le\frac{2}{x}.$$
Therefore

$$x\left(\frac{2}{x+1}\right)^x\le x\left(\frac{2}{\lceil{x}\rceil}\right)^x\le x\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x,$$

and your limit follows from the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil}\right)^x  \leqslant x \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$$